# C# Split the string

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I want to know how to split the string into different lengths or chunks. E.g. I want the name to be split into 0 to 19 with 0 the starting position and 19 the ending position. Any ideas on how I could do this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace employeefinal
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            employee i = new employee("Tom");
            Console.WriteLine(i.getString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public class employee
        {
            string employeename = "Name: John Smith, L, U, 012, 2, 7, 2, 4";

            public employee(string name)
            {
                this.employeename = name;
            }

            public string getString()
            {
                employeename.Substring(0, 19).Trim();
                return employeename;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that's what you already did in your getString, but C# String is immutable, so you'll need to return the SubString result

Comment: not working though as it is not retrieving anything in my main when starting the program

Comment: as both of us said in the comments, return employeename.Substring(0, 19).Trim();

Comment: Mind me asking why you want to do this?  There is probably a much better way to solve your problem.

Comment: so what does the letter `U` represent in that string..?

Comment: I am voting to close this because @ramteen1993 has failed to give enough information for example does he want to retun `John Smith` ||  `Name: John Smith` if he wants just the name then there is a much more efficient way to do this

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do as below, since strings are immutable in C#. When you do like you had, the "effect" is lost because you are not assigning that result to anything.

```
return employeename.Substring(0, 19).Trim();
```

Also note you lose original string once you assign "Tom" to it, through the constructor.

PS. When you pass start position and length which go out of bounds of the string instance you will get an exception.

Comment: Done this already as you can see in cod but not working though as it is not retrieving anything in my main when starting the program.

Comment: @ramteen1993: What you have done is different, try this.

Comment: @ramteen1993 just return the employeename.Substring(0, 19).Trim();

don't return the "emploteename"

Comment: @ArielB what's `emploteename`

Comment: @MethodMan it's the data member he wants to split (look at his post)

Comment: @ArielB perhaps you need to look at the post you have a typo you wrote the following in your comment `don't return the "emploteename"`

Comment: @MethodMan You're correct, that's a typo, i can't edit it sadly but of course i meant employeename

Comment: Substring return a new string. and you can catch a ArgumentOutOfRangeException fixing name size by 19 (or any unwanted result).

Comment: How would I go across doing another substring. I have tried to do one for getting the city which is another method called getCity and within this is "return employeename.Substring(20,20).Trim();". This does not seem to be working now on the console?

Comment: @ramteen1993:after you pass "Tom", employeename refers to "Tom". start position and length of substring must not exceed string length.

Comment: @Giorgi Thanks and any ideas on my previous comment which I left? I want to do two substrings but it is not working and keeps returning my original string? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As i understand, you want to split on comma separator, you have two options:

Option 01:

```
  public string getString()
  {
      return employeename.Substring(0, employeename.IndexOf(',').Trim();
  }
```

Option 02:

```
    public string getString()
    {
        return employeename.Split(',').FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Happy to Help you!

Comment: that's not what he asked, but if that what he meant, then KUDOS :)

Comment: If i not answer like this now, a new ask will be created, ^^
Thank you!

Comment: `return employeename.Split(',').FirstOrDefault().Replace("Name:", string.Empty);` even better no need for `OP` to have `Name:` since the code already tells us that it's pulling back first name based on the first `,` it finds

Answer (score 0):

following to what Giorgi said, change the implementation:

```
      public string getString()
        {
            if (employeename.Length > 19)
            {
                 return employeename.Substring(0, 19).Trim();
            }
            else
            {
                  //return error OR
                  return employeename;
            }

        }
```

also, your string is too short when assigning "tom" to it, you must make sure that you have atleast 19 characters..
i don't have VS in front of me, but basiclly the above implementation is better